# Delete row if any column contains one of the keywords

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I want to drop rows where any column contains one of the keywords

```
keywords=['Nokia' , 'Asus']

data = [['Nokia', 'AB123','broken'], ['iPhone', 'DF747','battery'], ['Acer', 'KH298','exchanged for a nokia'], ['Blackberry', 'jj091','exchanged for a Asus']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Brand', 'ID', 'Description'])
```

df before:

```
Brand      | ID    |  Description
----------------------------------------
Nokia      | AB123 | broken
iPhone     | DF747 | battery
Acer       | KH298 | exchanged for a nokia
Blackberry | jj091 | exchanged for a Asus
```

df after:

```
Brand      | ID    |  Description
----------------------------------------
iPhone     | DF747 | battery
Acer       | KH298 | exchanged for a nokia
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join all columns together with `+` or `apply` and then create mask by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined values by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
df = df[~(df['Brand']+df['ID']+df['Description']).str.contains('|'.join(keywords))]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df.apply(' '.join, 1).str.contains('|'.join(keywords))]
print (df)
    Brand     ID            Description
1  iPhone  DF747                battery
2    Acer  KH298  exchanged for a nokia
```

If need case not sensitive add `case` paremeter:

```
df = df[~df.apply(' '.join, 1).str.contains('|'.join(keywords), case=False)]
print (df)
    Brand     ID Description
1  iPhone  DF747     battery
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the examples. Can you explain me the 1 in `apply(' '.join, 1)`

Comment: @JohnDoe - it join all rows in DataFrame with ` ` for one column, Series, because neww Series for test in `str.contains`

Comment: @jezrael what if there's one column that has float, the second way will fail, how to solve it?     TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @PyBoss Convert column to strings `df['float cols'].astype(str)` or if possible missing values `df['float cols'].fillna('missing').astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[~(df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(keywords)).any(level=0))]
```

or

```
df = df[~(df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.contains('|'.join(keywords)))]
```

**Output**

```
     Brand  ID      Description
1   iPhone  DF747   battery
2   Acer    KH298   exchanged for a nokia
```